# Test if variable is declared in a class in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to do something like this. I want to test if a class has a variable of a given name or not.

```
if(classInstance.hasProperty(test))
```

In the example I want to test if test named variable is a member of the class. Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now there isn't a pure *Swift* way of doing this (`reflect` isn't enough), maybe objc runtime methods can help. Using [`class_copyIvarList`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_copyIvarList):

```
func hasProperty (obj: AnyObject, property: String) -> Bool {

    var count: UInt32 = 0
    var ivars: UnsafeMutablePointer<Ivar> = class_copyIvarList(obj.dynamicType, &count)

    for i in 0..<count {
        let name = NSString(CString: ivar_getName(ivars[Int(i)]), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        if name == property {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

Usage:

```
public class R {
    private var aVar = "Hi"
    private var anotherVar: Int = 0
}

hasProperty(R(), "anotherVar") // outputs true
```

Comment: you need to free the returned pointer from `class_copyIvarList` in ObjC, not sure about Swift

Answer (score 2):

Modified version of @pNre's solution without looping through all ivars:

```
func hasProperty (obj: AnyObject, property: String) -> Bool {
  return property.withCString {
    class_getInstanceVariable(obj.dynamicType, $0) != nil
  }
}
```

Comment: this seems to be what I am looking for but it doesn't work in swift 3.x - do you happen to know how to convert it?

Comment: @amok: I think you can just replace `obj.dynamicType` with `type(of: obj)`